# Problems with TYPE LIBRARY EDITOR

Tags: delphi

Years ago I wrote some COM DLL's i Delphi 4 (Client/Server). I did not have problems with that. Later I upgraded to Delphi 7 (Enterprise) and now I have a problems:

```
    File-> New -> Other -> ActiveX -> Automation Object -->  No problems.  

    Enter text "TESTPROJ" (CoClass neme) -->  No problems.  

// Multiple Instances - Multiple Instances
// Threading Model:   _ tmAppartment 
// Clickbox:  Generate support Code  -- Unclicked
```

When I click OK the Type Library editor appears with two LINES i the view-part (ITESTPROJ and TESTPROJ).  This seems to be correct.

```
I then click/ mark ITESTPROC. ITESTPROC gets marked.  Then I click NEW METHOD. 

A new Item (below ITESTPROC - named Method1) appears.  

Namebox says METHOD1. ID-box says 201.
```

BUT:

Invoke Kind- and TYPE-boxes are greyed ("Disabled") ..

I can read "Function" in the Invoke kind edit-box.

The problem is:   I can't make any functions - only procedures with this Editor.

(I was told (taught/read) that I make a function by setting the Invoke kind and the RETURN-type (in Parameters // ) but I can't use Invoke kind at all.

Can anybody tell me why ? And how do I make functions with that editor (need the TLB-file desperately)...

(I have tried setting the return type to HRESULT , string, integer etc. That gives me absolutely nothing- still procedures and procedures ONLY... (with /without parameters )..

Answer (score 2):

Methods and Properties in an Automation object are accessed via the [`IDispatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608.aspx) interface, specifically through its [`Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221479.aspx) method.  Any method you define is forced to an "Invoke Kind" of "Function", as it will be invoked with a `DISPATCH_METHOD` flag when `Invoke()` is called.  That cannot be changed, which is why the field is greyed out.  The "Return Type" on the Parameters page is set to `HRESULT` by default, **leave it that way**, see further below for why.

To define a "function" that returns a value, you simply create a method that has a **parameter** that uses a pointer data type and is marked with the `Out` and `RetVal` modifier flags.  For example, to create a function that returns a String, create a method with an `[out,retval]` `BSTR*` parameter.  The editor will generate a stub implementation that looks like this:

```
type
  TTestProj = class(TAutoObject, IConnectionPointContainer, ITestProj)
  ...
  protected
    function Method1: WideString; safecall;
  ...
  end;

function TTestProj.Method1: WideString;
begin

end;
```

All you have to do is return the desired string value, eg:

```
function TTestProj.Method1: WideString;
begin
  Result := 'my value';
end;
```

The `safecall` calling convention will handle the rest for you.  To report an error, simply raise an exception.  The RTL will call [`SetErrorInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221409.aspx) and return an appropriate `HRESULT` to the caller:

```
function TTestProj.Method1: WideString;
begin
  if some condition then
    raise Exception.Create('error message');
  Result := 'my value';
end;
```

If you do not raise an exception, the caller receives an `HRESULT` of `S_OK`.

*YOU* will see the method as a normal function in your implementation code, but the actual signature that the *CALLER* sees is `function Method1(out Result: WideString): HRESULT; stdcall;`.  That is why you have to leave the method's Return Type set to `HRESULT`.  Delphi's `safecall` calling convention re-orders things on the implementation side to make it easier to work with.

If you do not define any parameters that have the `RetVal` flag, the editor will create a "procedure" instead of a "function".  For example, if you create an `[out]` BSTR* parameter, the stub implementation will look like this instead:

```
type
  TTestProj = class(TAutoObject, IConnectionPointContainer, ITestProj)
  ...
  protected
    procedure Method1(out Param1: WideString); safecall;
  ...
  end;

procedure TTestProj.Method1(out Param1: WideString);
begin
end;
```

And the signature the caller sees is `function Method1(out Param1: WideString): HRESULT; stdcall;`.

Or, if you simply omit parameters altogether, the stub ends up like this:

```
type
  TTestProj = class(TAutoObject, IConnectionPointContainer, ITestProj)
  ...
  protected
    procedure Method1; safecall;
  ...
  end;

procedure TTestProj.Method1;
begin
end;
```

And the signature the caller sees is `function Method1: HRESULT; stdcall;`.

Comment: AHA, Now I see why. TAL (Thanks a lot).